# How to host an apache server on the web?

Tags: apache, web-hosting

I have already installed apache on my computer. Now I want to know how to host my server on the web so that others can connect to my server and view my sites.

Comment: Offtopic. This site is for programming questions. Try serverfault.

Comment: Even for ServerFault, you'll want to improve the question first.  What are your goals for this project?  Do you just need someone somewhere else to see something on your computer?  Are you looking for hosting?  Are you looking to host your own server?  Please elaborate on your usage scenario(s).

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to view your websites over localhost already, you should be able to just port forward through your firewall to allow external access.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are running your web-server on 0.0.0.0 interface. This can be checked by running the following command on linux `netstat -anlpt`. Inspect what ip is port 80 (or 443) listening. It should not be 127.0.0.1.
- If this is your home computer :

  - You will need to forward port 80 on your router(or 443 if using ssl) to port 80 of your computer. Your computer's IP address can be seen in `ifoncfig` or `ipconfig` (windows) output. Generally your router interface will be available at an address like `http://192.168.0.1` or `http://192.168.1.1` (depends on your router manufacture and settings).
  - Once you have got port forwarding set up, your website should be accessible from internet when one types your ip address. Your IP address as shown by http://whatismyip.com
- If this is not your home computer, then your website should be accessible via the public IP address of your server.
- If you have a domain name, you'll want to update the nameserver config for that domain to put a A record pointing to your server's IP address and create a equivalent vhost entry in apache. However, a domain name is not required to view your website, just http://w.x.y.z IP suffices (where w.x.y.z is the public IP of your server/computer)